# removing git commits from local history and pushing to github

Tags: git, github, commit

Ok so I have a bunch of commits from when I was configuring and testing my git installation and now I am trying to make a pull request back to the main repository but I dont want all the changes I made to be in the request.

How can I either remove a selected ranges of commits and leave them in the staging area

or

make a pull request with a specified commit range.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of doing this, but perhaps the easiest way is to create a new branch based on upstream, cherry-pick all the commits that you want in the request onto that new branch, and then issue a pull request for that new branch.  For example:

```
# Update your remote tracking branches:
git fetch origin

# Create a new branch based on the latest upstream master:
git checkout -b my-awesome-feature origin/master

# Cherry-pick some commits:
git cherry-pick abcdef
git cherry-pick 123456
git cherry-pick a1b2c3

# Push that branch to your github repository:
git push github my-awesome-feature
```

Then go to GitHub and issue the pull request.  (I'm assuming here that the remote `origin` points to the original project, and the remote `github` points to your fork on GitHub.)

This will ensure that your pull request will only contain the commits `abcdef`, `123456` and `a1b2c3`.

Comment: Ok that didnt do really what I wanted all the commits came with me how do I just throw away old commits, I want the changes I made I just want to revert them back to the staging area

Comment: If you still had all your commits, then I guess that the `origin` remote is your repository on GitHub rather than the upstream repository who you would like to pull your in.  Have you added a remote for the upstream repository, and if so, what is it called?

Comment: @BillPull, you are trying to do something against the nature of version control systems. They keep your commits so that if you made a mistake, you always have a point to return to. They won't let you delete your commits because they are protecting you against yourself!

Comment: @BillPull, if you really have commits in local repository that you didn't push to github, and you are really really sure you don't want them anymore, you can delete the whole directory of your project altogether and checkout from github again. My recommendation would be to back the whole thing up before.